# Pin header and first row on Excel like table with filter

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html-table, scroll

I have Excel like filter with table and what I need is I want to pin header and first row on scroll down. It should work even if I apply filter.

Please note the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6ng3bz5c/1/

I have tried the below  but not working:

```
$('tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
     $('tbody tr:nth-child(2)').css("down", $("tbody").scrollDown()); 
  });
```

First two highlighted rows should stick as Scroll down:

[image]

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `position: sticky` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)) in conjunction with `first-of-type` to handle the first row (in my own project I would style these using classes, but I'm using element selectors so as not to change your markup).

Knowing more about your css, you also might be able to change the `top` offset on the first row to something more responsive, but for demonstration I've just used the height that appears to work for me. You'll also want to add borders.

```
thead th{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:white;
}
tbody tr:first-of-type td{
  position:sticky;
  top:34px;
  background:white;
}
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('employeeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.XLfilters = { list: [], dict: {}, results: [] };
    $scope.markAll = function(field, b) {
      $scope.XLfilters.dict[field].list.forEach((x) => {x.checked=b;});
    }
    $scope.clearAll = function(field) {
      $scope.XLfilters.dict[field].searchText='';
      $scope.XLfilters.dict[field].list.forEach((x) => {x.checked=true;});
    }
    $scope.XLfiltrate = function() {
     var i,j,k,selected,blocks,filter,option, data=$scope.XLfilters.all,filters=$scope.XLfilters.list;
      $scope.XLfilters.results=[];
      for (j=0; j<filters.length; j++) {
       filter=filters[j];
        filter.regex = filter.searchText.length?new RegExp(filter.searchText, 'i'):false;
        for(k=0,selected=0;k<filter.list.length;k++){
         if(!filter.list[k].checked)selected++;
          filter.list[k].visible=false;
          filter.list[k].match=filter.regex?filter.list[k].title.match(filter.regex):true;
        }
        filter.isActive=filter.searchText.length>0||selected>0;
      }
      for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        blocks={allows:[],rejects:[],mismatch:false};
       for (j=0; j<filters.length; j++) {
          filter=filters[j]; option=filter.dict[data[i][filter.field]];
          (option.checked?blocks.allows:blocks.rejects).push(option);
          if(filter.regex && !option.match) blocks.mismatch=true;
       }
        if(blocks.rejects.length==1) blocks.rejects[0].visible=true;
        else if(blocks.rejects.length==0&&!blocks.mismatch){
          $scope.XLfilters.results.push(data[i]);
         blocks.allows.forEach((x)=>{x.visible=true});
        }
      }
      for (j=0; j<filters.length; j++) {
       filter=filters[j];filter.options=[];
        for(k=0;k<filter.list.length;k++){
          if(filter.list[k].visible && filter.list[k].match) filter.options.push(filter.list[k]);
        }
      }
    }
    function createXLfilters(arr, fields) {
      $scope.XLfilters.all = arr;
      for (var j=0; j<fields.length; j++) $scope.XLfilters.list.push($scope.XLfilters.dict[fields[j]]={list:[],dict:{},field:fields[j],searchText:"",active:false,options:[]});
      for (var i=0,z; i<arr.length; i++) for (j=0; j<fields.length; j++) {
      z=$scope.XLfilters.dict[fields[j]];
      z.dict[arr[i][fields[j]]] || z.list.push(z.dict[arr[i][fields[j]]]={title:arr[i][fields[j]],checked:true, visible:false,match:false});
      }
    }

    createXLfilters(employees, ['Country','City']);
})

var employees = [{
  "Name": "Manirul Monir",
  "City": "Sylhet",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Arup",
  "City": "Sylhet",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Person 1",
  "City": "Dhaka",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Person 2",
  "City": "Dhaka",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Munim Munna",
  "City": "Narshingdi",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Mahfuz Ahmed",
  "City": "Narshingdi",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Tawkir Ahmed",
  "City": "Gazipur",
  "Country": "Bangladesh"
}, {
  "Name": "Alfreds 2",
  "City": "Berlin",
  "Country": "Germany"
}, {
  "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
  "City": "Berlin",
  "Country": "Germany"
}, {
  "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
  "City": "Mannheim",
  "Country": "Germany"
}, {
  "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
  "City": "Strasbourg",
  "Country": "France"
}, {
  "Name": "Bon app'",
  "City": "Marseille",
  "Country": "France"
}, {
  "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
  "City": "México D.F.",
  "Country": "France"
}];
```

```css
.filterdropdown{
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
.filterdropdown.active{
  color: #005b9c;
}
a.filterlink{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.options {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
thead th{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:white;
}
tbody tr:first-of-type td{
  position:sticky;
  top:34px;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="employeeController">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" data="{{XLfiltrate()}}">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Country
          <div class="dropdown" style="float: right">
            <button class="dropdown-toggle filterdropdown" ng-class="{active:XLfilters.dict['Country'].isActive}" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu prop" aria-labelledby="btnSearchBatch" style="width: 250px; padding: 15px;">
              <div class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="filterlink" ng-click="clearAll('Country')">Clear All</a> | <a href="#" class="filterlink" data-dismiss="modal">Close(X)</a>
              </div>
              <form>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="XLfilters.dict['Country'].searchText" placeholder="Filter by Country" />
                <div>
                  <a href="#" class="filterlink" ng-click="markAll('Country',true)">Select All</a> | <a href="#" class="filterlink" ng-click="markAll('Country',false)">Select None</a>
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                  <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in XLfilters.dict['Country'].options">
                      <input id="countryOption{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="XLfilters.dict['Country'].dict[item.title].checked" />&nbsp;<label for="countryOption{{$index}}">{{item.title}}</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>City
          <div class="dropdown" style="float: right">
            <button class="dropdown-toggle filterdropdown" ng-class="{active:XLfilters.dict['City'].isActive}" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu prop" aria-labelledby="btnSearchBatch" style="width: 250px; padding: 15px;">
              <div class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="filterlink" ng-click="clearAll('City')">Clear All</a> | <a href="#" class="filterlink" data-dismiss="modal">Close(X)</a>
              </div>
              <form>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="XLfilters.dict['City'].searchText" placeholder="Filter by City" />
                <div>
                  <a href="#" class="filterlink" ng-click="markAll('City',true)">Select All</a> | <a href="#" class="filterlink" ng-click="markAll('City',false)">Select None</a>
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                  <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in XLfilters.dict['City'].options">
                      <input id="cityOption{{$index}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="XLfilters.dict['City'].dict[item.title].checked" />&nbsp;<label for="cityOption{{$index}}">{{item.title}}</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="emp in XLfilters.results">
        <td>{{emp.Country}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.City}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It will make header stick, but i want to make first row also stick. Please refer the image I have highlighted in image.

Comment: Oops missed that; seems to me that `first-of-type` works there. See updated answer.

Comment: Can this achievable on pagination? Like showing 10 records initially and showing all values in to filter and apply accordingly